# When emitting an event, does the data reach only the listeners or all the clients?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I've added two illustrations which are explain the question.

So, is there a true illustration? If so which one is true?

**Illustration 1**

[image]

**Illustration 2**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`io.emit(msg, data)` from the server sends to ALL clients that are connected to that server.  It does not matter whether the client is listening for that `msg` or not.  The data is sent to the client and if the client has a listener for that `msg`, then the event listener for that `msg` will be called.

If the client has no listener for that message, then the message will arrive, but have no listeners.  At that point, it's just like any event that has no listener.  The event is fired, but if there are no listeners, then the callback queue is empty, so there are no event handlers to call.

I don't quite understand the intended difference between your two diagrams, but the first diagram correctly shows the `data` being sent to all three clients.  The second diagram does not show that so it is not correct.

Keep in mind that it is not just the data that is sent.  The msg name is also sent with the data.  That's how the receiving client knows what event handlers to trigger for it.

---

You can think of a client kind of like this.

1. Here's an incoming message.
2. Do I have a listener for that message?
3. If so, call the listener.
4. If not, just ignore the message.

---

On the server side, you have choices about how you send the message that determines who it goes to:

`io.emit()` sends to all connected clients.

`socket.emit()` sends only to that particular client socket.

`socket.broadcast.emit()` sends to all connected clients except the one represented by `socket`.

`socket.to(room).emit()` sends to the clients in that room.

`io.of('chat').emit()` sends to the clients connected on that namespace.

Comment: @Efkan - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. This answer is just what I looking for. So, I've accepted the answer. Have a fabulous weekend!

Answer (score 1):

The first way is more accurate. How socket.io works is all clients are listening for a relevant event, if one happens to 'pass by', they will take the data form that one.

Here is an over simplified example of socket.io:

#### setup:

Client A:
`socket.on('attendance', data)`
Client B:
`socket.on('leaving', data)`
Client C:
`socket.on('attendance', data)`

### example scenario:

Server:
`io.emit('attendance', data)`
Client A:
`if 'attendance' == 'attendance' //true; do something with data`
Client B:
`if 'attendance' == 'leaving' //false; do nothing`
Client C:
`if 'attendance' == 'attendance' //true; do something with data`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tahnks. Your answer is true too. I've accepted other one. But I gave reputation (+10) for this one too.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help